# Why is Chrome not starting on my Mac?

Tags: google-chrome, mac

I am totally unable to open Chrome on my Mac. 
I have tried to resolve it using folder permissions as recommended here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7494016 but to no avail.

I tried these steps but there is nothing wrong with permissions. One hint something odd is going on is that using `ps aux` or `htop` is that I can see some Chrome processes and I see all this garbage about `--field-trial-handle=<whatever>`. When I kill these I get the error pop-up regarding Gmail offline below:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or alternatively how to uninstall **Gmail offline** on my Mac's chrome without being able to open Chrome? I *do not* want to completely uninstall and reinstall Chrome, but I'm open to that if nothing else works. Thanks!

Comment: How did you install Chrome? You can use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Maybe this solves the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to download the standalone installer (not the online one) and install Chrome again? Your preferences would be safe, along with your bookmarks, etc... but you'd start afresh. You issue probably comes from a corrupted .plist file somewhere, though, but you should start with reinstalling Chrome altogether, then take it from there.

Comment: I will give reinstalling a shot if I need to go that route...